# Oracle, skip duplicate rows on specific key by sort

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How I can skip the duplicate record when list sorted, for example,
I have table:

```
EmpID   Date          Dept    OtherField
1       2017.02.03    11      1
1       2016.02.03    11      2
1       2015.02.03    13      7
1       2014.02.03    21      6
1       2013.02.03    21      12
1       2012.02.03    13      333
```

I need get:

```
1       2016.02.03    11
1       2015.02.03    13
1       2013.02.03    21
1       2012.02.03    13
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a group by statement with a max(). Give it a whirl and if you need help, update your question to include the query you've tried.

Comment: group by will return only one record by employee + department, I just want to skip duplicate record when sorted! So, I would like to know in which department employee work in any point of time. Employee can return to department, he work before. Also can be duplicate records, when date changed, but department not (because in table have more fields, which can be changed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) would suit your needs, I believe:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 11 dept, 1 otherfield from dual union all
                     select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 11 dept, 2 otherfield from dual union all
                     select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 13 dept, 7 otherfield from dual union all
                     select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 21 dept, 6 otherfield from dual union all
                     select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 21 dept, 12 otherfield from dual union all
                     select 1 empid, to_date('03/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 13 dept, 333 otherfield from dual)
select   empid,
         min(dt) dt,
         dept
from     (select empid,
                 dt,
                 dept,
                 row_number() over (partition by empid order by dt)
                   - row_number() over (partition by empid, dept order by dt) grp
          from   sample_data)
group by empid,
         dept,
         grp
order by empid,
         dt desc;


     EMPID DT               DEPT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2016.02.03         11
         1 2015.02.03         13
         1 2013.02.03         21
         1 2012.02.03         13
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea: `Partition by` duplicated fields to get first row using `row_number()`
Implementation:

```
select EmpID, Date, Dept, OtherField
from ( select EmpID, Date, Dept, OtherField, 
                row_number() over (partition by empid, dept order by date asc) rwn
       from table_name) t
where rwn = 1;
```

According to your `expected result`, I assume that you need partition by `empid, dept`, and get min of `date`. If not, feel free to change the query for your purpose.

Comment: The scenario is more complicated. It shows an employee's history of working in different departments. If an employee worked in the same department in two different periods, separated by working in other departments, then the OP needs the earliest date of employment in the "first" department for EACH of the periods, not just the single absolute earliest date. The method sometimes called "tabibitosan" as Boneist has shown in his Answer is the right approach for this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select EmpID, MIN(Date) as Date, Dept
from t
group by EmpId, Dept
order by EmpID, MIN(Date) DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will eliminate duplicate records:

```
select UNIQUE ...
```

Comment: Unique is not work because date is different. I need the last record.

Comment: Your problem is not exactly clear to me. I showed you how to eliminate records that are completely identical. Your problem is that you first want to select on some colum(s), then add the date in some way. When you have analyzed your problem in an exact way, the solution will be near.